# box2d b2_staticBody position problem

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, positioning, box2d

I've encountered a weird problem about positioning bodies in cocos2d/box2d.

If I set b2BodyDef type as b2_staticBody, I can't set bodies on any position out of multipliers of PTM_RATIO. Let me explain:

```
#define PTM_RATIO 32.0

...
myBodyDef_1.type = b2_staticBody;
myBodyDef_1.position.Set(320.0/PTM_RATIO, 320.0/PTM_RATIO);
...
```

and

```
...
myBodyDef_1.type = b2_staticBody;
myBodyDef_1.position.Set(333.0/PTM_RATIO, 333.0/PTM_RATIO);
...
```

gives the same result. No change in position. Difference of 13 pixels means nothing.

If I make the difference more than PTM_RATIO it appears 1 PTM_RATIO (32px) away.

For example:

```
...
myBodyDef_1.type = b2_staticBody;
myBodyDef_1.position.Set(358.0/PTM_RATIO, 358.0/PTM_RATIO);
...
```

Diffrence of 38px, but appears only 32px(1 PTM_RATIO) away.

I tried using direct values like 1.0 and 1.1
It didn't work. I can't get rid of multipliers of PTM_RATIO.

One more hint, if I use b2_kinematicBody as type, it works perfect.

Any idea?

Comment: and what position is shown by debugger ?

Comment: 320.0 and 333.0 both appear on 320. 358.0 appears on 352

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding explicit conversation: `358.0/((float)PTM_RATIO)`.
try myBodyDef_1.position = b2Vec2(333.0/PTM_RATIO, 333.0/PTM_RATIO); and explicit conversation here.
try

```
float x = 333.0/PTM_RATIO;
float y = 333.0/PTM_RATIO;
myBodyDef_1.position = b2Vec2(x, y);
```

Let me know the result please

Comment: 358.0/(float)PTM_RATIO worked. that's weird because giving direct value (11.1875) doesn't work.